# Networking Units: Not getting expected performance from 100Mb Ethernet

Tags: networking, network-attached-storage

Our company has a brand new NAS, and the idea is that we will be able to use it for fast, shared access to our data on our network.

It's a fairly simple 2-disk system, but from what I understand, it should reach speeds of about 40mb/s. We have a 100mb/sec network between our PC's and the NAS.

However, we're only getting NAS speeds of around 8-10mb/sec. What could the bottleneck be?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You are confusing your units.

M = mega
m = milli
B = byte
b = bit

When referring to disk usage, we measure throughput in megabytes per second, or MB/s. Notice the capital **M** for mega and the capital **B** for bytes.

When referring to network performance, we measure throughput in megabits per second, or Mb/s. Notice the lowercase **b**.

A bit is eight times smaller than a byte. You can figure out your 100Mb/s network's maximum theoretical throughput in MB simply by dividing by 8. `100 / 8 = 12.5`.

TCP/IP has ~ a 10% overhead, as does Ethernet, so realistically you'll only see about 80% of that at the high end. A little more basic math shows that `12.5 * .8 = 10`. You should expect to be able to write at about 10MB/s over your 100Mb/s network. This lines up perfectly with what you are seeing.

---

**tl;dr** - Capitalization is important.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all, from either a disk perspective, or a networking performance configuration perspective.

Comment: Of course it does. What part of the question do you not think is addressed? He has a 100Mb LAN and is only getting 10MBps throughput to his new NAS. This is the expected value for this configuration. My answer explains the math behind it and explains the confusion that the OP had with his units of measure. Not to mention that the OP selected this answer as correct, meaning that it answered th question to his own satisfaction.

Answer (score 3):

You should go for 1000 Mbps (gigabit) Ethernet. The pieces are cheap to buy these days and your speed will be faster. You should be able to reach the 40 MB/s.

Just make sure that your networking cable is all Category 5e. If it isn't at least that good, things will get weird.

Comment: It'll be 4 times faster, as it'll bottleneck on the NAS unit (if numbers in the question are correct)

Comment: @Sirex: Oh well, yes that is true. But the *network* will be 10x faster.

Comment: If I remember correctly gigabit pulls a theoretical 125MBps, if taking into account the math done above you will run at 100MBps when running gigabit.

Comment: Hum i plugged my computer directly to the switch and i think our middle cables where not cat5e just cat5 so that's why we got only 100mbps. With 1000mbps i got arround 40MB/s read and 20MB/S write. I guess the limit is now on the NAS wich is slower to write than to read...

Comment: @florent Either your NAS is trash, your disks are trash, or there's another bottleneck somewhere else. 20MB/s is really bad. A **single** Western Digital Green 5200 RPM should be able to sustain writes faster than that.

Comment: @MarkM: If you look at the reviews of NAS equipment, you will find that 40/20 MB/s is not an unusual speed.

Comment: @ZanLynx maybe for some DLink box meant for home use. I wouldn't touch anything like that for workplace usage.

Comment: my hunch is that's exactly what this is. However why not try plugging directly into it (with Cat 6 if possible) and see what speeds you get to take the network out of the equation entirely ?

Comment: To conclude all this, we switch to a Professional NAS wich has a différent price (X2,5) and shows significant improvment in read/write speed (i would say X3)
Thx a lot for all thoose help :)

Answer (score -2):

Make your device can handle the throughput. I have a 100mbps connection but the router I'm using can only handle 50mbps max. The new netgear business class routers are something to look into.

Comment: Abe, the question was answered and there was nothing wrong with his configuration!